# remove css rule from <style> in head jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding some CSS rules to the `<style></style>` tag in `<head>` via jQuery which cannot be added inline because most of them are pseudo-classes (:hover,:focus, etc...).

Simultaneously is added a class to the respective DOM element.
The class is removed if a button "clear" is clicked but :

How can I remove the CSS rule in the `<style/>` once this button is clicked or the style element changes? I think in some way I need to go through the whole `<style>` tag in the head section but have no idea how to do this.

My code for one element so far is:

```
if ($('.color:eq(4)').val() != '') {$("#preview iframe").contents().find('body a').addClass('test');}
$('.clear').eq(5).click(function(){ $("#preview iframe").contents().find('body a').removeClass('test');});
$('iframe').contents().find("#style").append(".test:hover{color:#"+ hover1 +"!important;}");
```

where var hover1 is the val() of the input field from where the the styles are choosen and added.

Comment: Why remove the rule? Why not have a style that is based off a class and remove that class when done?

Comment: The way I've done this on the rare occasions I've had to is to keep a list of the current information the style element needs to have, and then rewrite the element entirely when updating the list.

Comment: @epascarello:  If the user is playing  with the interface there are remaining a lot of junk rules in the < style >

Comment: @Someone33 search CSSStyleDeclaration.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder : Can you give me an example? Would be nice...